# person simulation and motion capture data documentation

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi, the feature page at [Gazebo Features](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Features) states that motion capture data can be imported. I cannot find anything in the tutorials or the API. Does anyone have a pointer ? Thx.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5327/person-simulation-and-motion-capture-data-documentation/) by [Vincent Rabaud](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/629/vincent-rabaud/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-01-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The motion capture replay (called Actor in Gazebo) has a bit of code rot.

Here is a [tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/intermediate/animated_characters)

Here is the [api](http://gazebosim.org/api/2.2.1/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Actor.html)

Here is an old [SDF file](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/fc137d08bd373a4469d0d2017b7ed77986d6767d/sdf/models/actor_demo.model?at=default)

Here is the related [issue](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/538/gazebo-actor-sdf-13-parser-error)

Please vote for the issue to move it up in our queue.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2014-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vincent Rabaud](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/629/vincent-rabaud/) on 2014-01-28**:
Thx ! I looked for person and motion capture while I should have looked for character animation, skeleton